# How do I get the closest date to today with an ISO date format?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that's to read an array of objects and find:

1. if `customerAuthorizedTime` is `null`
2. if `customerAuthorizedTime **is**`null`, then find the one with the closest date to today, the current day.

**My attempt:**
My attempt to filter out all objects to find all the `customerAuthorizedTime` is null and then find the closest date

```
const filteredData = data.filter((a: MemberAppointment) => a.customerAuthorizedTime === null)
const filteredAppointment = // use .sort() or .find() to find closest date?
```

I stop short because I'm unsure of how to find ISO dates that are closest to the current day.

**My second attempt:**
I wanted to try to perform a more direct approach with `.find()`:

```
const currentDate = new Date().toISOString()
const filteredAppointment = data.find((a: MemberAppointment) => a.customerAuthorizedTime === null && // date is closest to today's date)
```

But the problem remains that I'm not sure how to find the closest date to today's date in ISO format. Is there a way to also satisfy this condition with `moment.js`?

My dataset:

```
const data = [
  {
    'appointmentId': 403749,
    'masterAppointmentId': 403749,
    'memberPartyRoleId': 1262903,
    'description': 'Training (30 minutes)',
    'startTime': '2019-06-09T22:00:00-04:00',
    'mustCancelBy': '2019-06-09T22:00:00-04:00',
    'activityTransactionId': 19726389,
    'customerAuthorizedTime': '2019-06-09T00:33:02-04:00',
  },
  {
    'appointmentId': 403750,
    'masterAppointmentId': 403750,
    'memberPartyRoleId': 1262903,
    'description': 'Training (30 minutes)',
    'startTime': '2019-06-09T21:00:00-04:00',
    'mustCancelBy': '2019-06-09T21:00:00-04:00',
    'activityTransactionId': 19726390,
    'customerAuthorizedTime': null,
  },
  {
    'appointmentId': 403748,
    'masterAppointmentId': 403748,
    'memberPartyRoleId': 1262903,
    'description': 'Training (30 minutes)',
    'startTime': '2019-06-09T20:00:00-04:00',
    'mustCancelBy': '2019-06-09T20:00:00-04:00',
    'activityTransactionId': 19726388,
    'customerAuthorizedTime': null,
  },
  {
    'appointmentId': 403747,
    'masterAppointmentId': 403747,
    'memberPartyRoleId': 1262903,
    'description': 'Training (30 minutes)',
    'startTime': '2019-06-09T19:00:00-04:00',
    'mustCancelBy': '2019-06-09T19:00:00-04:00',
    'activityTransactionId': 19726387,
    'customerAuthorizedTime': '2019-06-09T00:13:18-04:00',
  }]
```

Comment: it would cost you O(N) but you can always run through the data array, use the moment().diff(date, 'days') function and keep the smallest absolute value. you could always just get the now date (new Date().toISOString()) and then find the absolute diff and keep it.  I think that would be the simplest solution. Do you only care about the future? so you can also remove past dates from the search method and cut down the search

Comment: just realized new Date().getTime(); returns the utc timestamp. much easier to compare to that. so same thing. just convert all dates into timestamp and find the smallest absolute or positive dff. still O(N)

Answer (score 0):

Traversing all appointments and calculating the closest datetime (in future) to today. If there is no items(array is empty) or all items have `customerAuthorizedTime == null` - func's result will be current datetime.

```
function dateOfClosestApointmentToToday(items)
{
    let now = (new Date()).getTime();
    let found = null; 
    items.filter(function(itm) {
        if (!!itm.customerAuthorizedTime) {
            let t = (new Date(itm.customerAuthorizedTime)).getTime();
            if (!found || t > now && t < found) {
                found = t;
            }
        }
    });
    return (new Date(!!found? found: now)).toISOString(); 
}

//
// get closest datetime
//
let closest = dateOfClosestApointmentToToday(data);
```